# Set sql_mode in CakePHP Schema

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

What's the CakePHP way to set MySQL's SQL mode when you run `Console\cake schema create`?

The non-CakePHP equivalent is to run this query in the PDO constructor using the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` parameter:

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create/edit the `AppSchema` constructor (beware that you might have more than one instance in your project), grab the data source and execute the query:

```
class AppSchema extends CakeSchema {
    public function __construct($options = array()) {
        $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->connection);
        $db->execute("SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'");
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
}
```

This will load your schema using the desired SQL mode. More specifically, it will *not* enforce a given SQL mode for the application itself.

Possible use cases:

- Get strict for early error detection

  ```
  SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
  ```
- Relax settings to load incomplete sample data

  ```
  SET @@SESSION.sql_mode=''
  ```

---

In more general terms, you can (and I suggest you do) change the SQL mode globally for the entire connection by editing the corresponding property in the `DATABASE_CONFIG` class at `app/Config/database.php`:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        // …
        'settings' => array(
            '@@SESSION.sql_mode' => "'TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'",
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: am using CakePhp 2.3 and am stuck using this strict method. My server is a shared one. So that I don't have the phpMyAdmin root privileges. The "DATABASE_CONFIG" is not worked in my code. Can you guide me please

Comment: @NishalK.R How could possibly `DATABASE_CONFIG` not work? And what exactly do you need root privileges for? BTW, PhpMyAdmin is an entirely different application.

Comment: I tried to set `sql_mode` globally in the server via `phpMyAdmin`. It needs root privileges to do that. I added the `DATABASE_CONFIG` as like you mentioned in the `database.php`. But it seems not to work.

Comment: @NishalK.R Yes, you need special privileges to change settings for the entire server. But that seems unrelated to this question.

Comment: What am done now is executed the query `$db->query( "SET @@SESSION.sql_mode=''" );` in `AppController` and it's working now. But I feel it's not a standard method. When am looking to the method that you defined in the `config`, it seems standard. But it's not working in my application.

Comment: @NishalK.R "Does not work" is not a lot of information. This feature was [added in CakePHP/2.4.0](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/ab510d17009a677230ca63045f02a95717d68ae3). If you have any specific issue perhaps you should ask a question and provide your details.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the DB source.

```
$config['flags'] = [
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';"
];
```

[See the connect() methods code](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-Mysql.html#152) of the MySQL driver class.

But this might be a problem when you use `$config['encoding']` at the same time... See line 163. :( This cries for a fix in the core.

But you could extend this class (MysqlExtended or something like this) and change it as needed and use it. Just overload the connect() method. And then use this driver instead of the original for your connection.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose this has been rewritten for CakePHP 3 but I'll be stuck with 2.x for a long time. Anyway, do you think it's possible to run the query from `AppSchema`? I've been playing with the `before()` hook and `ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->connection)->fetchAll()` but I can't get the details right.

Comment: Oh, forget the last part of my comment. This project (not started by me) actually has three different `AppSchema`. I'm testing the wrong one.

Comment: Like I said, just extend the driver class and set up a db connection config for it. Then use it with your schema, see: http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-CakeSchema.html#52

If you just want to run a query you can use Model::query() or DboSource::execute().

Comment: Thank you for the `DboSource::execute()` tip, I didn't know the method existed because I was relying on my IDEs code completion... That fixed my exact needs; I've composed a proper answer to help others in the future. But please keep your answer, the tip to extend `DboSource` looks useful to set a SQL mode for the whole app.

Answer (score 2):

For CakePHP 3 in app.php, section 'Datasources', add:

```
'flags' => [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
]
```